# Versions management of python packages

Tags: python, virtualenv, git-submodules

What is a best practice to manage a different versions of packages?
I know about virtualenv but i am not sure it is suitable in my case.

#### My problem:

Consider that i have 2 projects (P1, P2) which both use 1 small project (P3).
I use git submodules and add P3 to both P1 and P2.

Then i have P4 which uses all projects described above and P4 needs the latest version of P3.

How to deal with it?
I want P1, P2, P4 to use their own version of P3. But when i build P4 i have only one version of P3.

#### Projects structure:

All projects have such structure (some files omitted):

*P4* example:

```sh
├── project_name (sources are here)
├── Makefile
├── submodules
│   └── P1
│       ├── submodules
│       │   └── P3
│   └── P2
│       ├── submodules
│       │   └── P3
│   └── P3
├── tests
└── setup.py
```

#### How subprojects are imported:

No surprises here, all projects import *P3* in that way as it was the only one version installed.

So *P1* uses:
`from P3 import something`

And P4 also uses:

`from P3 import something`

`from P1 import something_else`

Comment: You can't have two different versions of a single Python project installed at the same time in one Python environment. If two projects both depend on a third project, but different versions of it, then it is (near) impossible to solve in Python currently. Is that what the question is about, or did I misunderstand? One commonly used alternative would be to **vendor** _P3_ in each of the other projects. But since you are talking about _git submodules_ I guess you are kind of _vendoring_ already, or am I missing something?

Comment: @sinoroc, I add P3 as a submodule to P1, P2 and P4 and use it there. Why "near" impossible? Is there some way? Is it really Python weakness? How other languages deals with it? 
Sorry for that much questions :)

Comment: Yes, many questions, they would require answers that wouldn't fit in comments, and would be too opinionated for sure. Let's stick to the core issue... Could you edit the question to show the general directory structure of P1 (for example) and how the P1 code that imports P3 is written (the `import ...p3...` statements)?

Comment: @sinoroc, sorry for the late reply. I updated the question. Hope it will help to understand my problem more clearly.

Comment: OK, I don't see anything particularly difficult here. Since you seem familiar with _git submodules_ then just go with it. What's really blocking you to go further? Maybe show a concrete [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The general rule is that running multiple versions of the same project within a single Python environment is not supported. Obviously (like any other kind of limitation in software) there are ways to go around it, but they all require quite a bit of work.

From what I can gather from this particular question, I believe *vendoring* could be a fitting technique to circumvent this limitation while requiring as little modifications as possible to the current state of the project.

**1. with git submodules**

- Keep *P3* in a different *git* repository.
- Use *git submodules* to have two different copies of *P3* in the main project.

**2. with the vendoring tool**

- Promote *P3* to its own Python project with complete packaging.
- Use the [*vendoring* tool](https://pypi.org/project/vendoring/) to have two different copies of *P3* in the main project. See for example how *pip* uses it in ["*Switch to a dedicated tool for vendoring pip's dependencies #7485*"](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7485)

---

> What is a best practice to manage a different versions of packages? I know about virtualenv but i am not sure it is suitable in my case.

It is not. Virtual environments could help for example to work on two different projects using two different versions of the same library. But the two projects would need to live in two different virtual environments. So you couldn't have one single project importing simultaneously from two different versions of a same library.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. It seems that vendoring really could help in my case, but since all try to avoid it as a bad practice, maybe it would be better to add some custom tools for submodules management (like a tool for ensuring that installed submodule version is compatible with all submodules in the project tree)

Comment: Yes, _vendoring_ could help, but should be a last resort solution, since it is indeed a bad practice (for many reasons, security being one of them). Sometimes there simply isn't any fitting combination of the versions of the dependencies, and vendoring is one of the only way I know of to work around it. -- On the topic of trying to find a fitting combination of dependencies: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926641/11138259

Answer (score -2):

Virtualenv will work, why you thought it wouldn't work?

Comment: then, i don't see how may it work. When the final project is build, virtual environment contains only one version of P3...
For example P1 needs P3=1.0.0, P2 needs P3=2.0.0, P4 need P3=2.0.1
If P3=2.0.1 would be installed, P1 will not work...

Comment: What about running multiple venvs? It's normal to have a `.buildenv`, `.prodenv` etc. You are not limited to just using a single `.venv`.