# Python: testing & loading different git commits of same package

Tags: python-3.x, github, pip, installation, version

I have a python package on github, and I can install different commit versions of it using e.g. `pip3 install git+https://github.com/my/package@commithash`. I would like to benchmark various different commits against each other, ideally comparing two versions within the same python script, so that I can plot metrics from different versions against each other. To me, the most obvious way to do this would be to install multiple different versions of the same package simultaneously, and access them using a syntax something like

```
import mypackage_commithash1 as p1
import mypackage_commithash2 as p2

results1 = p1.do_something()
results2 = p2.do_something()

plot_comparison(results1, results2)
```

But as far as I can see, python doesn't support multiple packages of the same name like this, although https://pypi.org/project/pip3-multiple-versions goes some of the way. Does anyone have any suggestions for ways to go about doing these sorts of comparison within a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's too broad of a question to give a clear answer...

Having two versions of the same project running in the same environment, same interpreter session is difficult, near impossible.

First, maybe have a look at this potentially related question:

- [Versions management of python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60247521/11138259)

**1.** From reading your question, another solution that comes to mind would be to install the 2 versions of the project in 2 different virtual environments. Then in a 3rd virtual environment I would run code that looks like this (kind of untested pseudo-code, some tweaking will be required):

```
environments = [
    'path/to/env1',
    'path/to/env2',
]

results = []
for environment in environments:
    output = subprocess.check_output(
        [
            environment + 'bin/python',
            '-c',
            'import package; print(package.do_something())',
        ],
    )
    results.append(parse_output(output))

plot_comparison(results)
```

**2.** Another approach, would be to eventually use [*tox*](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) to run the test program in different environments containing each a different version of the project. Then have an extra environment to run the code that would interpret and compare the results (maybe written on the filesystem?).

**3.** Maybe one could try to hack something together with `importlib`. Install the 2 versions under 2 different paths (`pip install --target ...`). Then in the test code, something like that:

- modify `sys.path` to include the path containing version 1
- import (maybe *importlib* can help)
- run test 1
- modify `sys.path` to remove the path containing version 1 and include the path containing version 2
- import again (maybe `importlib.reload` is necessary)
- run test 2
- compare results

Comment: Could I import the packages from 2 local versions under different names? E.g. I could clone the entire github repo twice, to local folders `mylibV1` and `mylibV2`, checkout versions V1 and V2 in the respective dirs, then simply do `import mylibV1.mylib as V1` and `import mylibV2.mylib as V2`, then use `V1.do_something()` vs `V2.do_something`?

Comment: (p.s. this isn't using `pip`, obviously. But it might work for me.)

Comment: Try it. It could work, but most likely it won't. One thing coming to mind that could prevent this from working is the way the imports are done internally in this project. Usually when one does `import somepackage` or `from somepackage import something`, these are _absolute imports_ and `somepackage` is a _top-level package_. Placing the packages under another directory, for example `MyProjectV1`, makes it so that `MyProjectV1` is the _top-level package_. So unless all imports inside `somepackage` are relative (for example `from . import something`), the imports will most likely fail.

Comment: Thanks. It *does* seem to work for me:
`>>> import versions.tsinfer_efbafff.tsinfer as V1
>>> import versions.tsinfer_1c17964.tsinfer as V2
>>> V1.__version__
'0.1.4'
>>> V2.__version__
'0.1.5.dev140+g1c17964'`

Comment: Looking at the [code of what I assume is the project in question](https://github.com/tskit-dev/tsinfer), I doubt this technique could work. This project definitely uses absolute imports to itself, which would be broken because of the extra directory levels. It's very important to make sure you don't have another version of the project already installed in the environment (`path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip show tsinfer` and `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip uninstall tsinfer`), because if it were the case then some code would be imported from this version instead of the version in your directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking. This is indeed the project, and you are right that I haven't properly tested e.g. by removing already installed versions. When I do so, as you surmise, the import fails. Damn

Comment: trying your method 3, but `importlib.reload` doesn't seem to reload the packed with the new sys.path information, and simply reloads the previous one.

Comment: If you already have some code, then I'd suggest to ask a new question with a [mcve] to get some more focused help on that specific technique. Link it in the comments for me to find it.

Comment: Will do. Thanks so much for your very useful help.