# pip complains about dependency versions but installs them anyway. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, dependencies, boto3

I have a requirements file defined like this:

```
requirements.txt

botocore==1.15.11
docutils==0.16
```

When I hit `pip install -r requirements.txt` I see this error:

```
botocore 1.15.11 has requirement docutils<0.16,>=0.10, but you'll have docutils 0.16 which is incompatible.
```

However, when I hit `pip list` I see this as the output:

```
botocore        1.15.11
docutils        0.16   
jmespath        0.10.0 
pip             18.1   
python-dateutil 2.8.1  
setuptools      40.6.2 
six             1.15.0 
urllib3         1.25.9 
wheel           0.34.2
```

This indicates that the two dependencies were installed as per definition in the requirements.txt file. Why is complaining about it if it's not a problem? If it is a problem, how did they get installed?

Comment: "_However, when I hit pip install I see this as the output:_" Did you mean `pip list` instead of `pip install`?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some well-known issues (limitations and bugs) with *pip*'s current dependency solver. A new (better) one is in progress. It can already be tested. More details in this answer and its links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926641/11138259

With that said, these two requirements are incompatible:

- `botocore==1.15.11`
- `docutils==0.16`

As can be seen in the [`setup.cfg` for *botocore 1.15.11*](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1.15.11/setup.cfg):

```
[bdist_wheel]
universal = 1

[metadata]
requires-dist =
    python-dateutil>=2.1,<3.0.0
    jmespath>=0.7.1,<1.0.0
    docutils>=0.10,<0.16
    urllib3>=1.20,<1.25.8; python_version=='3.4'
    urllib3>=1.20,<1.26; python_version!='3.4'
```

It's still possible to instruct *pip* to install such a combination (one that is advertised as not compatible) anyway. And *pip* will warn about this conflict, as you showed in your question, or by running `pip check` (which by the way, as far as I know, as of today, uses the newer dependency resolution already):

```
$ pip check
botocore 1.15.11 has requirement docutils<0.16,>=0.10, but you have docutils 0.16.
```

The imports and the executed code might still work without any (apparent) issue though. For example: it could be that *botocore 1.15.11* is not actually entirely incompatible with *docutils 0.16*. Either the code path that would trigger an issue is not hit, or the restriction `docutils<0.16` was just made as a preventive measure.

Comment: So does this have to do with a limitation within pip and not with the packages?

Comment: Oh. Reading the question again, and running some tests on my side, indeed... These two requirements `botocore==1.15.11` and `docutils==0.16` seem indeed incompatible: https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/1.15.11/setup.cfg

Comment: Right, my confusion is to why pip installs them anyway and how it all still works.

Comment: **1.** Well, if I am not mistaken _pip_ installs it anyway because it's current dependency solver is still a bit weak. And if the user _forces_ the installation somehow, for whatever reason, then _pip_ has no reason to stand in the way. **2.** As to how it still all works: you mean the programs, the imports still work ? It could be that _botocore 1.15.11_ is not actually entirely incompatible with _docutils 0.16_. Either you haven't hit a code path that would trigger an issue, or the restriction was just preventive.

Comment: Okay, I think I get that now. So it's a bit of a loose end in pip

Comment: Anything else you would like to be cleared up before accepting that answer?