# Working with conflicting python dependencies

Tags: python, pip, dependency-management

Package `python-a` depends on `package-b`:`2.0.0` and `package-c`:`2.0.0`. At the same time package `python-b`:`2.0.0` depends on `package-c`:`1.0.0`.

So package `package-c` is required in both version, `1.0.0` and `2.0.0` at the same time and causes pip to run into a version conflict.

Is there a way's to work with dependencies in different versions like that?

Comment: condo environments are best for these situations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60602214/11138259